# Linked List C code hangs without returning from 'free-ing' function

Tags: c, linked-list, free, freeze

For a program that I am working on, I have a doubly linked list. I now have to figure out a particular node where a particular data (called `id`) becomes negative, and then dereference the following nodes and also free the memory. When I call this function (pasted below), the last print statement is executed and prints on screen. However the program doesn't return to main. It simply hangs. (Right after this function call, I have another print statement which doesn't get executed and the program hangs there endlessly).

```
static void clear_ghosts(particles *plist)
{
  particles * temp = plist;

  while(temp!=NULL) {
      if(temp->p->id < 0)
      {
          break;
      }
  temp = temp->next;

 }

 if(temp)
 {
     particles * current = temp;
     particles * next;
     while(current !=NULL)
     {
         next = current->next;
         free(current);
         current = next;
     }
     temp = NULL;
 }

 printf("\n Finished Clearing \n");
 return;

}
```

Here `plist` is a linked list of type `struct particle *`. `plist` has data `p` which itself is a struct and has member data like `id` etc. I need to loop through the list and terminate the list when the member id that is negative is encountered. I am getting the output "Finished Clearing", but the function is not returning to main.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Post the code in main, it appears the problem might be there.

Comment: How do you tell it's not returning to main?

Comment: If it is really doubly linked, you should do something about the `prev` fields as well.

Comment: u r breaking 1st while loop on the node where id < 0 and then terminating the list from that node but wat about the node just previous to this node? u r not setting previous node's next to NULL...in a way corrupting the list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all elements you are trying to `free()` have been allocated with `malloc()`? If, for example, some of those pointers point to memory on the stack, all kinds of horrible things  might happen when you try to `free()` them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say its a double-linked list you should set the previous element's next pointer to NULL:

```
if (temp)
{
   if ( temp != plist )
   {
     temp->prev->next = NULL;
   }
...
```